# Hybrid document library in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, development

I have a document library in SharePoint Online,

When I add a new file to this document library, I need to get a copy to this file in document library in my SharePoint on-premise

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such hybrid document solution. Learn more about [hybrid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/hybrid/hybrid).

For your requirement, I suppose you need a remote event receiver to copy the new file from SharePoint Online library to on premise.

[How to create a remote event receiver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-a-remote-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-add-ins)